# undefined behavior (extra symbols) added to my char string when printng with printf in C program

Tags: c, struct, towers-of-hanoi

I wrote this program to help someone else and as a learning exercise but now I am confused as to why the strange additions are happening? Help is greatly appreciated

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

typedef struct
{
    char str[1000];
} arrType;

typedef struct
{
    char *str;
} ptrType;

ptrType message = {"start"};

int main()
{
    int choice;
    int i;
    char temp;
    char begmessage[1000];
    char endmessage[1000];
    printf("Would you like to (1) encrypt or (2) decrypt?: ");
    scanf("%i", &choice);
    scanf("%c", &temp); // temp statement to clear buffer
    printf("You chose: %d\n", choice);
    printf("Type your message: ");
    scanf("%[^\n]", begmessage);
    ptrType message = {begmessage};
    printf("\nThe message you typed is %s \n", message.str);
    if (choice == 1) 
    {
        for (i = 0; (i < 1000 && message.str[i] != '\0');) 
        {
            if (isalnum(message.str[i])) 
            {
                endmessage[i] = putchar((message.str[i] + 1));
                i +=1;
            } 
            else 
            {
                endmessage[i] = putchar((message.str[i])); i +=1;
            }
        }
    printf("\nYour message is now: %s\n", endmessage);
    }
    if (choice == 2) {
        for (i = 0; (i < 1000 && message.str[i] != '\0');) 
        {
            if (isalnum(message.str[i])) 
            {
                endmessage[i] = putchar((message.str[i] - 1));
                i +=1;
            } 
            else 
            {
                endmessage[i] = putchar((message.str[i])); i +=1;
            }
        }
    printf("\nYour message is now: %s\n", endmessage);

    } 

}
```

Here is the output:

> Would you like to (1) encrypt or (2) decrypt?: 1 You chose: 1 Type
> your message: High Tower
>
> The message you typed is High Tower  Ijhi Upxfs Your message is now:
> Ijhi Upxfs���
>
> Would you like to (1) encrypt or (2) decrypt?: 2 You chose: 2 Type
> your message: Ijhi Upxfs
>
> The message you typed is Ijhi Upxfs  High Tower Your message is now:
> High Tower���

this line "High Tower" comes from where?
and on the last line where does the "���" come from.  I did a search on stackoverflow and the internet but the symbol � is not recognized...

Ran the program again and got similar results:

> Would you like to (1) encrypt or (2) decrypt?: 1
> You chose: 1
> Type your message: High Tower
>
> The message you typed is High Tower  Ijhi Upxfs Your message is now:
> Ijhi Upxfs�;�
>
> Would you like to (1) encrypt or (2) decrypt?: 2 You chose: 2 Type
> your message: Ijhi Upxfs
>
> The message you typed is Ijhi Upxfs  High Tower Your message is now:
> High Tower@

Comment: Were you ever planning on setting the terminator in your `endmessage` ?

Comment: C requires you to indicate the end of a string with the value `'\0'`. You never added this byte to your string, so you get garbage after the part that you filled in. This is one of the most basic features of C strings.

Comment: Thank you so very much WhozCraig and Barmar I added int end; before main() and this:             end = i;
            }
    endmessage[end] = putchar('\0');  and the garbage is gone but still it prints out the result before my printf statement?

Comment: Since in each `if.. else ..` you increment `i` by `1`, there is no reason not to use `i++` in the increment of your `for` loop, e.g. `for (...; ...; i++)`. It will make the readability better. Also. There isn't any need to use a single-member struct for `arrType` and `ptrType` -- you can simple use the array or pointer -- which will also tidy up the syntax.